# How to avoid glitched Rendering outcome? [like digital glitch effect]

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

Basically I was doing a small animation and rendering it sequentially, at a particular frame I noticed weird grey glitches, some sort of scattering miss calculation. I tried tweaking with render settings, watching videos for optimization and yet this problem exists even after single frame render, doesn't show up in viewport though.

[image]

Comment: Well, I found where the problem is from, Its Motion blur. Turning it off fixed the issue.